# Get doxygen to process files from #include directives

Tags: doxygen

I have a directory tree with a lot of source.  I'd like doxygen to process some of the source, but not all.  It should process the files that will be compiled to generate the target that the documentation is for.  I.e., the docs for an executable should come for the sources for that executable.

So I thought, since I must already have a list of sources that make up the target, that I could pass this list to doxygen.  This almost works, but there is a problem.  I don't have a list of every header file, since this isn't necessary to build a target, and don't want to manually maintain such a list.  We've had auto-dependencies for decades now.

I thought doxygen could find headers on its own via parsing the sources files listed in `INPUTS`.  And indeed it does find them.  Doxygen scans the source, finds the #include lines, looks for the files named in them, and even opens them.

But it doesn't process them for directives and generate docs.

Is there something I'm missing here?  I know I can give doxygen a directory tree to scan recursively, but I don't want it to scan all the files.  Just the ones that are part of the target the documentation is for.

Comment: To the best of my knowledge there is nothing like this in doxygen. Doxygen is not a compiler. Maybe best to submit an enhancement request (including a small example) to https://github.com/doxygen/doxygen/issues/new

Comment: It would only need to preprocess, not compile.  And it already does do this!  By running doxygen under strace, I can see it finds and reads in every header it should.